# how to use jacoco using mvn command line

Tags: maven, jacoco

I am looking to just run jacoco as maven target instead of running clean install

I have been using following commamd with cobertura. Is there a similar way to run the jacoco.

mvn cobertura:cobertura

Regards
Lalit Kumar

Comment: Are you trying to generate coverage report as html?

Comment: i am going to generate html as well push the result xml to sonar

Comment: try `mvn test jacoco:report`